# I have a new answer for one (or more) old questions

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, self-answer, old-questions

I've been struggling with an issue all day, finally to discover the solution. I've found several SO questions that directly cover this issue, and all have been marked with an answer that is different to my own.

I'd like to record my answer on SO for future. What is the etiquette here? Should I add an answer to one of the already answered (old) questions? or should I create my own question and immediately answer it?

Comment: I did exactly this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179672/unlimited-strength-jce-policy-files). If your answer is good, it will slowly climb toward the top even if the other answers got a five year head start.

Comment: I don't see what's confusing. It's precisely the same as any other question.

Comment: Not only is it ok, it's great.  No one should get the impression that if you don't give an answer within 10 minutes of the question being asked that you are not allowed to answer an existing question.

Comment: I answered an old question on `virtualenv` with how we would do it using `virtualenvwrapper` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767382/including-global-package-into-a-virtualenv-that-has-been-created-with-no-site/16217474#16217474 - and my answer has almost overtaken the older one because people find it to be useful.  Append a good answer to an old question - odds are good that the people who will really appreciate it will see it and upvote.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Only ask (and answer) a new question if your problem isn't actually covered by any existing question.

If your issue is "directly covered" by another question then you **shouldn't** ask a new question. Add your answer to **one** of the questions you have found.

Additionally, if you have found "several SO questions that directly cover this issue" then at the very least you should be flagging some (or indeed all) of them as duplicates of the one with the best answer. You should add your answer to this question.

Comment: Why not answer every existing question you can? With potentially different appropriate answers?

Comment: @Basilevs if the questions are different then you can do that. However, the implication of the question was that they were all the same.