# Promoting new answers to old questions

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty, old-questions, outdated-information

I was searching for some information on a topic and found the following question: [Timer doesn't want to start again after it was disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551856/timer-doesnt-want-to-start-again-after-it-was-disabled).

I recently began learning about `async`/`await` from .NET 4.5 and was surprised to see that nobody had answered suggesting `async`/`await`. [So I decided to provide my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25001367/88217), but since the question is older than one month and from a user who has very few reputation, it is unlikely that this question will be maintained or even marked as answered. Yet it is the <del>second</del> first result you get when you google for something like: "[C# timer wont start again after disabled](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23%20timer%20wont%20start%20again%20after%20disabled)".

This made me think: How do we promote new answers to old questions?

For example, we have this vast knowledge base of C# questions and answers. But as the language evolves, there will be better ways to solve certain problems. How do we ensure that the newer approaches can be highlighted after the original activity in a question dies down? Sure, the original answers will work, but buried down at the bottom could be a more modern and more suitable solution that will be overlooked by the casual googler.

I read the following Q&As, but they don't seem to quite line up with my concern:

- [I have a new answer for one (or more) old questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256207/i-have-a-new-answer-for-one-or-more-old-questions)
- [What's the policy on down voting previously correct but now outdated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265749/whats-the-policy-on-down-voting-previously-correct-but-now-outdated-answers)

Comment: People who are active on SO use Google as well. What makes you think [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256207/i-have-a-new-answer-for-one-or-more-old-questions#comment29265_256207) doesn't apply here?

Comment: I tried downvoting an old crap answer that was marked as the right one, that gave me -1 rep.

Comment: Related: **(1)** [Is it ok to start a bounty on a question you have answered to promote your answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254956/456814), and **(2)** [What kind of bounty message is acceptable for promoting your own answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266231/456814).

Comment: @Brunis Yes, downvoting answers costs a reputation point.

Comment: @AirThomas my concern is that if I were using Google and I came across a solution that was marked as correct, and indeed it did work, I could miss out on an opportunity to leverage newer and possibly better approaches.  If the first one worked, and I didn't know any better, I would tend to upvote that one and move on.

Comment: @TaRDy If you were more interested in leveraging newer and possibly better approaches than in finding something that Just Works, you might take a moment to at least scan through the list of alternatives. Either way, you would have chosen to use this resource in a way that best aligns with your priorities. The system works - with an asterisk, perhaps, but it does work.

Comment: If it's a good answer to a question that gets a decent amount of views, you probably don't need to promote it. E.g. my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21681010/2846923) was two years late, but 1. I added something that no other answer had and 2. The question gets a lot of views.

Comment: You may also check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215241/232130).

Comment: @sancho.s Not that an answer being *outdated* (referring to older versions of an environment) is generally not the same thing as an answer being *incorrect*.

Comment: I know. I pointed it out, as your topic also was mentioned, by exclusion, with a couple of links to similar questions.

Comment: Basically, get over it.  I have dozens of pieces of brilliant software that are residing in the bottoms of bit buckets, because some bean counter killed the project.  And dozens of truly outstanding answers here that got lost similar to yours (or even worse, were effectively deleted with the question).  Life's not fair, and neither is SO.

Comment: **how do we promote new answers to old questions?** You can do things like bounties, comments, etc., but the big one is already done for you, and you mentioned it: **it is the second result you get when you search**.  That means that over time, the new answer, if it's good, will accumulate upvotes.

Comment: @HotLicks maybe you didn't understand the intent of this discussion, it wasn't about my answer being overlooked, it was about the broader issue of technology changing but most searches pointing towards questions that have technically correct answers but may have alternative solutions that are more suitable when using newer versions of the technology

Comment: There is a fiction that SO is about creating a long-term "archive" of software info.  Look at a dozen random questions, though, and 11 of them will be stuff that won't even be of interest next week, let alone in 5 year.

Comment: And technology doesn't always change as fast as you think.  Many fundamental concepts (which SO spends relatively little time on and often actively discourages) go back decades, and I've on several occasions solved a knotty problem by using a concept from 20-30 years ago that younger programmers simply had never been exposed to.

Answer (score 33):

You can always add a bounty, there's even a fitting bounty reason:

[image: bounty reason]

A bounty can often bring an old question back, for example [Eclipse fails to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339841/eclipse-fails-to-start). You can always start a bounty, and then add your answer, or vice-versa.

Other than that, I know [first hand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11701951/1139697) that late answers can actually rise to the top. But sometimes you need a little bit of patience (note that there isn't an accepted answer).

Comment: It's also not dependent on any activity on the part of the user who asked the question. +1.

Comment: This seems like a good solution for more active users to invoke the mechanism, but someone like myself won't be able to do many of these.

Comment: @TaRDy Keep in mind that if you use a bounty to draw attention to your own answer, and that answer is in fact useful and high quality, the rep cost of the bounty can be offset or exceeded by the rep benefit of upvotes on your answer. So the quality and importance of the addition (and to at least as great an extent, the popularity of the subject matter) are more significant than the activity level of the answerer.

Comment: Bounties are pretty much useless, in my experience.

Comment: @AirThomas you need to get at least 5 upvotes to break even with a bounty. Now, when people are really reluctant to upvote, this is mostly impossible.

Comment: @SalvadorDali It takes more or less time depending on the popularity of the question, is all.

Comment: If you use a bounty to promote your own updated answer, who do you award the bounty to at the end of the week since you can't award it to yourself? Giving the rep to someone else doesn't really matter but when someone else's outdated answer gets the bounty label, it just reinforces the supposed "correctness" of that answer.

Comment: This answer is being linked to from here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324384/how-can-recent-answers-catch-up-with-popular-old-answers

Answer (score 8):

You can put a bounty to draw attention to the question, but this isn't necessarily what I would recommend.

If you anticipate that the changes will be substantially different, it may be worth asking a new question, specifying that you're interested in solving the problem with a newer version, and linking to the question regarding the old version to show that you've at least looked into the problem a little, and to avoid closure as a duplicate. (It may also be worth editing the original question to leave a quick note specifying which versions it applies to if nothing was said at the time, and pointing to the new question.)

It somehow depends on the already present for the old question, and perhaps whether the new version is completely different (although you might not know that in advance).

The problem with mixing versions in the same Q&A thread, is that you could have 3 answers for version 1 (more or less when the question was asked) and, following your bounty, another 3 answers for version 2, and another 4 for version 3. There are a few downsides to this:

- Mixing solutions that try to answer what are effectively different questions (now and then) can generally be confusing to the reader.
- There's nothing wrong with [old answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265753/372643). Others might actually still be interested in version 1. It can then be a bit difficult to compare the ranking of the vote count, to choose what applies to you, as a reader (although it's generally worth reading multiple answers anyway).
- This makes the "accepted answer" a bit awkward. The askers may or may not want to change what the accepted answer is, or be in a position to do so. Perhaps they're no longer interested in the problem or they are unable to try with the new version so as to choose a new accepted answer.

Comment: this got me thinking, since the overall goal is for the greater good of teaching the "correct" way, wouldn't it make sense to keep it all on the same original question (so long as the parameters of the question haven't changed too drastically).  Ideally, couldn't we mix the versions by creating a community wiki version of the answer that addresses the different versions?  For the C# examples one would list at the top how to go about it in the latest version and then say later "if you must use legacy versions such as x.xx, you would want to do it this way..."

Comment: "*the overall goal is for the greater good of teaching the "correct" way*": actually, that's not really the overall goal. The aim of SO is to build a repository of programming knowledge, it is not about *teaching*. There's a subtle difference, but you'll find that teaching as such isn't particularly encouraged (e.g. we close similar question as duplicates, without actually *explaining* why, and questions that ask for general guidance tend to be closed for being too open-ended). Pedagogy isn't a strong point of SO.

Comment: You'll also find that while CW can be an option is has never really worked considering the general way SO is designed (and all its rep incentives). SO is in fact *not* designed for writing answers collaboratively. Rep is really based on individual's answers (or questions). SO is really oriented towards providing multiple answers to the same question, it's not Wikipedia. Even in a CW answer, you could find a situation where one editor wants to reword the whole thing, going against what previous authors/editors have said. (... cont'd ...)

Comment: (...) SO has an editing mechanism which is really designed for *editing* (at most). This isn't quite the same thing as having multiple *authors* working together. There is also very little to acknowledge proper authorship in CW answers (in the same way you get the "*answered [by ...]*" box under each answer. Sure, sure can browse the revision history, but it doesn't necessarily make it easy to asses who was an actual author and who just fixed a couple of punctuations mark. This makes is rather difficult to provide proper attribution under the CC licence then.

Comment: Regardless of the subtleties of knowledge base vs learning, the point is to help others by making the information available.  If CW's don't work due to authorship and rep concerns, there has to be a better way to aggregate generations of answers into the most visible response.  It is fine to think that as responsible SO users we would come across a question and review all possible responses provided, yet I would doubt the vast majority of people coming to the site through google would bother to venture past the first accepted answer if it simply worked for them.

Comment: It's worth leaving a comment or an editors note saying there's something more applicable to newer versions, even with a direct link to that answer, even a mention in bold in the question saying there's a new question (if you choose to ask a new question). I'm not saying there's a general right or wrong way to handle this problem (it depends on the question), I'm just saying that there's currently no good mechanism to aggregate multiple answers together. (There are little contradictions like this between what SO wants to be and what it encourages through its design and mechanisms.)

Comment: *"I'm not saying there's a general right or wrong way to handle this problem (it depends on the question)"* - I fully agree. This is a "use your own best judgment" situation with many potentially reasonable approaches.

Answer (score -13):

I would suggest editing the question with a note saying something to the effect of :
"There is a new method of solving this in the latest framework. See X's answer"

If the latest framework actually makes the question irrelevant (eg. A question about how to get around the lack of async main is irrelevant now C# 7.1 introduced async main) this should for sure be noted in the question.

Comment: No, don't do this. Answers do not belong in the question.

Comment: Not as answer. As a note telling you to look at answer X

Comment: That doesn't belong in the question, either. Questions should include only information pertinent to the question itself, not metadata. If *anything*, you might post this notice as a comment. But it generally is not necessary or recommended to do so. If it is your own answer that you're calling attention to, comments like this could be perceived as self-promotion.