# Policy on upvoting old answers

Tags: discussion, upvotes, old-questions

I am going to start out by stating that I have searched for this, or a similar question, on Meta. I've had no luck in finding a question close enough to this one, so I figured I'd create a new one! (Forgive me if there is an existing question and I have missed it)..

I often find myself search SO for answers to simple problems and in almost every case I have found the solution! The thing is, most of the threads are always at least a year old. I want to hit the up vote on that answer as it was helpful to me but I always face the same dilemma in deciding if it this up vote is even needed here.

So I'm looking to you guys to clear this up for me, and anyone who may be facing the same ordeal.

1. Is an up vote on an age old thread worth anything to the community?
2. Is it helpful or just useless?
3. Should I stop up voting them?

Comment: You should upvote whenever you want. If something's helped you why would you not want to? If it's helped you, it's definitely worth something to the community and the wider world. It's the point of answering almost!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Promoting new answers to old questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267018/promoting-new-answers-to-old-questions)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no such thing as an 'old thread'. Questions and their answers are either helpful to you or they are not, and your votes help highlight *to other people* what might be helpful to them too.

Other, future visitors to the post will appreciate those votes, as they too then can see what was helpful and what was not.

How long ago an answer was posted doesn't really matter in that process.

Answer (score 4):

It's absolutely helpful. It keeps valuable answers closer to the top where they are more visible. I look at old questions and answers all the time; I am grateful for when they are upvoted so I can see them and I upvote them so others can see them as well.