# Introduce an "Obsolete Answer" vote

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, answers, voting

### Background

There is a meta discussion going on, on [How to deal with hugely upvoted, bad answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272570/1461424). And as an answer, I wrote:

> You can downvote, comment, and provide a better answer, of course. But...
>
> If the obsolete answer is really old, it is most probable that your comment/answer will be drowned for a long time. I think this is where we have to take a leaf out of Wikipedia's book.
>
> When an article in Wikipedia has obsolete facts, and if Wikipedians notice this, they can let others know it by adding [`{{Update|inaccurate=y}}`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Articles_with_obsolete_information) to the page. The result is this:
>
> [image: Screenshot from Wikipedia]
>
> This is essentially equivalent to ***"This answer is obsolete"*** comment on Stack Overflow. But note that, unlike in Stack Overflow, Wikipedia does not naturally drown that flag. It is displayed on the very top of the page. This has several advantages:
>
> 1. Wikipedia users know up-front that the information in the article *might* be obsolete. They do not have to *use* that information in order to realize that it is obsolete.
> 2. If they visit the article, without *any* inspection, Wikipedia editors immediately know that the article should be fixed. So the correction process is faster.
>
> I think we should have something similar on Stack Overflow. **A flag for obsolescence:** a flag not for moderators, but for the community. And enough flags (3? 5?) should display a message about the answer.

And this has gained popularity (currently +51/-1), so I am converting the idea to a feature request.

### Feature Request

1. Introduce a way to vote an answer for obsolescence.

   1. This privilege should only be granted to users above certain reputation. (Proposing 200+ reputation, aka avid users).
   2. The vote should read something like: "**This answer is obsolete**: This answer may contain obsolete, out of date information. Or it needs to be updated considering recent software or standard updates."
   3. Voters must provide a clear description about why she thinks the answer to be obsolete.

      [image: Voting]
2. After voting is done, reason should appear as a comment under the answer.

   ***Rationale***:

   1. Poster of the answer is notified automatically.
   2. It will be useful for other people who take time to read the comments.

   [image: Comment]
3. If an answer accumulates a certain number of obsolete votes (proposing 3 votes), a message should be displayed above the answer for the attention of community. *"This answer may contain out-of-date information. Please validate this answer and consider providing an answer with recent information."*

   ***Rationale:***

   1. Future visitors know up-front of the risk of using the information on the answer.
   2. Community can know that the answer is obsolete without inspecting it.
   3. People are hesitant to edit someone else's answer. This message will help lower the mental barrier.

<kbd>[image: Warning]</kbd>

4. After this message, once an edit is made, the obsolete votes are cleared. If the edit does not make the answer up to date, it should be rejected on review, and votes for obsolescence should be restored.

### Other things

This is intended to work on well formed, highly upvoted, but old and obsolete answers. As we have seen, **downvotes are too slow to drown the obsolete answers**.

Or we can use this for answers that does not include solutions for standards introduced afterwards (e.g. Answer posted in the time of HTML4 may have a better way to do the same thing with HTML5). It is to improve the wiki aspect of Stack Overflow, not to be used as a quality control tool on new answers.

If this ever gets approved:

1. The messages described in the feature request can (and I think should) be changed to more elegant texts.
2. Mentioned reputation levels can be discussed.

Comment: I know that many questions are abandoned by the asker once they accept, but perhaps a notification to the asker to encourage them to choose a new answer would help at least some of the time?

Comment: And I'm not sure if flagging an answer usually counts as "activity" on a question, but if it doesn't in general then in this case it should, so as to attract up-to-date answers.

Comment: @hobbs: that would only work if one of the newer answers is (still) relevant. *But* if an older toolkit has certain limitations and the accepted answer provides a workaround, then surely a modern answer **using a newer version** is "not an answer"! It might need extensive editing of the original *question*. In such cases I would recommend leaving both question *and* (outdated) answers as they are (possibly with a note saying so).

Comment: Do you have more examples of answers that this could/would be applied?  I know the root cause (dealing with highly voted old answers) has been brought up before, but how much of a problem is this really?  Are there hundreds of answers that this could apply to?  Or are we looking at only a handful?

Comment: There is an argument for a post notice that details that the answer may no longer be the best for current versions. You're assuming that no one uses older versions, which is incorrect.

Comment: @psubsee2003: I have encountered some in past months. But I admit that they are not everywhere. But the ones I happen to see were kind of canonical questions/answers which were highly upvoted, aka the long standing "wiki"s of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Ben: No I am not assuming that. e.g. "Answer posted in the time of HTML4 may have a better way to do the same thing with HTML5". Then someone can _add_ the HTML5 solution to the answer as well.

Comment: Why force an edit of the current answer then @Krumia?

Comment: Because some questions/answers become canonical sources. And there's a traffic > upvotes > more traffic feedback loop for those. There are essentially a wiki. Everyone comes there when they have that particular question. It needs to include recent things as well.

Comment: @psubsee2003: [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/470542/1461424)

Comment: @psubsee2003 http://stackoverflow.com/a/181291/526741 used to be the chosen answer and had this issue at one time. My answer luckily got voted up by users that knew the correct answer (and comments indicated that the previously selected one was out of date) and has since been marked as accepted, but it took quite some time for that process to happen, and users could have gotten incorrect information in the meantime.

Comment: You might do better calling this a "vote" instead of a "flag" to avoid confusion with flags for moderator attention.

Comment: If you can identify that an answer is obsolete - i.e., that it *was correct* but is *no longer correct* - you should also be capable of editing it in a way that clarifies its scope. This is much easier and more effective than downvoting is, or flagging would be. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23631486/2359271) of a clearly-scoped, well-received, outdated answer.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if users *edit the answer* rather than adding a huge feature for obscure cases.

Comment: I'd suggest using tag score instead of reputation. That way users voting to mark as obsolete must have some amount of experience with the technology.

Comment: @connor: I _did_ think of that, but you can't really trust tags on this. A question might be about [tag:mysql], but may have tags [tag:php], [tag:html], etc... Also, someone may have enough points on `someframework` tag, but the question is not tagged `someframework`, but `someframework3.14`.

Comment: @Krumia I agree it isn't perfect, but is probably much more reliable than plain rep. Some tags also go together often. A user with a high php score likely has a decent html score as well. It appears to be working for the duplicate hammer and that has a much higher threshold for tag score.

Comment: I don't really support this idea. Sure, software and libraries get updated, but that doesn't mean they aren't used by anyone anymore. In theory, newer and more relevant questions/answers will get more upvotes anyways (thus making them easier to find.)

Comment: An additional suggestion: once the answer acquired enough obsolete votes to get a message printed at the top, **OP should be able to uncheck** the "accepted" check-mark without the answer having been edited (i.e. the message should count as an edit that lets OP uncheck).

Comment: @R only votes are locked, not the accepted answer mark. The OP is free to unaccept any time they want.

Comment: This topic has already been discussed a few times, as far as I remember. For example [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265440/372643), [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265753/372643) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267038/372643). My general suggestion for this is to leave an editor's note saying that this only applies up to version X. Either start a new question for version Y (if there are already too many answers) or write a new answer stating explicitly why it applies from version Y only. Answers are never really obsolete.

Comment: @sampathsris How is this going? I found this post when I found the following situation.

Post A -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071135/import-file-using-string-as-name

is marked as a duplicate of  post B -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301134/how-to-import-a-module-given-its-name

The issue being, post A has the following: more up to date, and implements best practices. While Post B "The correct one" is advising users against best practices.

I submit this comment to help add fuel and examples for why this is necessary.

Comment: @KyleSwanson: Nowhere, actually. Thanks for yet another concrete case.

Comment: Referenced in meta post *[Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405302)* (2021-02-18).

Comment: Maybe (also) relaxing the vote-locking policy should be considered? Currently one cannot revoke a vote if the answer did not change, even if it got outdated.

Answer (score 147):

Separate from [my earlier comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272651/introduce-an-obsolete-answer-flag#comment100614_272651), the biggest concern I have is the difference between answers that are valid for an older version of a language, frameworks, or software (that is still available and used), and an answer that is completely obsolete.

The example question seems to be a perfect example of something that is completely obsolete and contains little value anymore.  It would be a perfect candidate for such a notice.

But I am concerned such a flag would be overused on good answers that target older (but still available ) frameworks.  The flag encourages editing the answer to be up-to-date, but do we really want to lose the content in those answers?  Depending on the language and the software, many users still depend on old versions of software simply because that is all they have, or they are tasked with maintaining legacy systems.

In short, there is a difference between legacy and obsolete and we need to ensure that the intent of the flag is to target the obsolete answers without slowly removing the legacy content that still has value.

---

So the next question is what *should* be done.  I think this is where [my previously linked comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272651/introduce-an-obsolete-answer-flag#comment100614_272651) comes into play.  Just how big of a problem is this?

As of this writing, there are 13.8 million answers on the site.  How many are truly and completely  obsolete that have no value at all?  Are we talking about hundreds (<0.001% of all answers)?  How many obsolete answers do we need before the feature becomes worth the effort to implement?  And even if there are more answers currently that it seems worth it, once we flag the existing answers, how often would the flag be needed in the future?

The point that I am trying to make is while this seems to be a problem, there just doesn't seem to be value in a complex system to identify them when there probably aren't all that many in the big picture.  The best solution would be concentrated community driven effort to clean up these questions, and either edit to clean them up and/or downvote them if editing is impossible.

Comment: Agreed. Here's an example from my own history: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332925/how-to-inject-the-request-into-a-service. @Cerad's originally correct answer was superseded by my own when a new version of Symfony came out. He updated his answer to reflect the change, and both answers were left live. Tagging answers with 'correct for version 2.4' seems like an enormously complicated for a problem that doesn't exist all that much.

Comment: I have to admit that implementing this is a lot of work. One thing we can do is to make a habit of putting a warning in the answer itself, rather than a warning comment. But this could very well become an edit war. Maybe there is no other way than to nag the answerer constantly until that person updates the answer.

Comment: I think you not only need to take into account the *amount* of obsolete answers that are an issue today, but also the *impact* of those answers, which could be measured as them being the accepted answer, having a lot of upvotes and/or being on a very popular question.

Comment: @skiwi I'm not disputing they could be a problem. But like any software feature, you have to look at this from a cost. Is it really practical to invest the time to creating a feature that will only be used on a small scale when there are other options

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, that is exactly why you also need to take into account the impact of those answers *while* valuating the cost, as else you get a skewed analysis... I still think there are quite a bunch of these answers around though.

Comment: What if the answer sorting algorithm favored recent votes over older votes? That way, if a new answer to the question appears that gets 20 votes, and the older answer with 50 votes has had some downvotes/few upvotes, then you can just show the 20 vote question first.

Comment: @CoryKlein: Since an answer's vote history is mostly hidden, most people don't know about it -- and a sort that includes it would have a weird enough ordering to result in bug reports.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311425/many-answers-in-android-camera-are-spreading-a-lie) is another example that shows how the wizdom of the crowd not necessarily works well. The comments point to some other dangerous misunderstandings that can not find a plausible resolution within the current SO protocol.

Comment: @AlexCohn I saw your MSO post earlier.  I'm not really familiar with android, but is that truly an example of an obsolete answer?  Was the "wrong way" ever correct?  Or one that is flat out wrong and misconception of the implementation is being spread around?  The issues may be similar, but my stance is based on the idea that obsolete is not necessarily wrong, just not up-to-date.  But something that was never correct should probably be handled much differently

Comment: these answers were never correct; sometimes, they happen to work (because Google did poor job of defining this API), and what happens is that people try the solution on their device, happily click "⬆︎" and forget about this; later they probably have to spend a while to resolve the situations when this does not work for somebody on the other side of the planet, but there is no incentive for them to go back and downvote the answer that caused this.

Comment: @AlexCohn I'd say that cases where wrong practices is probably a different issue that may need a different handling.  I agree that downvoting is probably not enough, but then you start to get into a murky area of "how wrong is enough to justify special treatment".

Comment: I think downvoting outdated content is not fair - The person gave correct answer at that point in time - why penalize him?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava fairness is relative.  Is it fair to the dozens or even hundreds of users searching for an answer and find one that has hundreds of upvotes only to find out that the answer is not the best practice anymore or is even wrong now.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Then invent a flag which marks that as obsolete - why should person who answered should suffer - mainly his reputation?

Answer (score 40):

I'm not sold on the need for a flag (moar flags!!).

If you know enough to know that the answer is out of date, then you also know enough to either:

- edit the answer to correct the obsolete information
- edit (or suggest an edit) close to the top of the answer mentioning that it is obsolete

There - no flag required, and you either get a corrected answer or a warning similar to the Wikipedia one you mentioned.

I would also suggest that there would be very few answers that are obsolete in totality while the question remains valid and current - this means the answers are only partially obsolete (so you can fix it), or the question is obsolete and needs to be deleted along with its answers.

While the proposed flag has a certain feel-good flavor to it, I doubt its efficacy. We need answers (especially highly up voted ones) fixed or deleted - we don't want some place holder notices or meta flags that don't achieve much by themselves. A flag or placeholder notice *warns* people, but it doesn't substantively improve the answer, and they have only marginally more value than a comment.

Comment: As I see it, it will have lot of value than a comment/answer burried in all those upvoted answers. I know that this suggestion is quite dreamy :). But the belief that downvotes will take wrong answers to bottom over the time is a dream too. It does happen, but takes a very long time. This proposal is to reduce the latency.

Comment: And if you say "placeholder notices does not improve the answer" this must be true for Wikipedia too. What do you think the purpose of `{{Update}}` in Wikipedia? It is an encouragement for people to improve content.

Comment: @Krumia You are correct that down votes will not work for popular answers that become incorrect a long time after they are created. However editing an obsolete notice in is very simple - no flag required. But even that is ultimately sub optimal - we need the information to either be *fixed* or to *go away*.

Comment: "we need the information to either be fixed or to go away". It would have been great if we could do that. But the reality is canonical answers need to be updated with the change of technology, especially with web technologies. For example [How do I limit the number of rows returned by an Oracle query after ordering?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/470542/1461424). This used to be very hard on versions before 12.1, but after that we have a nice concise syntax. People _have_ provided answer for 12.1 versions, but they are very slow to come to top.

Comment: Editing the answer to correct the outdated information is not generally appropriate; it's substantively changing the author's answer, and could introduce incorrect information or views that the author does not want attributed to them. This has been discussed before. Of course you can edit to add a notice that "this answer may contain outdated information" manually, but the request here is to automate that process.

Comment: @R.. It's a collaborative site, which is exactly why people can edit or suggest edits for other's answers. I'm not saying the old info should be removed - it was clearly correct at some point. I'm suggesting that the **new** info is **added**, and some distinction is made between the new and old. The [example used](http://stackoverflow.com/a/441429/109702) in the previous thread is an ideal example of collaborative editing. The answer needs to be correct or it needs to be gone - the feelings or intentions of the author shouldn't come into it.

Comment: @slugster: I don't have references handy, but this issue has been discussed before and the conclusion is that it's generally not appropriate to modify the meaning of somebody else's answer. You can write a new answer if you don't like the existing ones. Edits are for clarifying what the author was already saying, fixing formatting, grammar, small typos/bugs in code, etc. in ways that do not change the intent of what was said.

Answer (score 32):

[As George pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272661/2359271), flags are generally useful for bringing posts to the attention of moderators. In order to update or replace an obsolete answer, you need to bring that post to the attention of community members, preferably targeting experts in the relevant subject matter.

There's already a feature that *attempts* to provide that (though I'm not sure it's effective), namely, [bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/254929).

[image]

There's [some amount of existing discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=bounty+system) about the effectiveness of the bounty system, including [recent data showing they're effective at generating question views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238906/254929). In theory, they *should* be drawing more attention from users who follow one or more tags on the question, including subject matter experts.

But it's **not hard to find problems** with the bounty approach.

- **Bounties are associated with questions, not answers**. While we know they get the question more views, we know less about their relationship with existing answers. Will people read the text describing why the bounty is awarded? Of those who do, will they be able to identify the outdated answer(s)?
- **This bounty option is either obscure or widely considered to be useless**. Consider that this question has attracted (currently) 84 votes, 350 views, 6 answers (2 unicorns) and 20 comments without any mention of bounties.
- **Guests and new users can't do it** (you need 75 rep), while users with low or moderate amounts of rep may not be willing to pay the cost (50+ rep, non-refundable) just to improve the quality of one answer. Even for users willing and able to pay the cost, it's frankly easier to mention the post in a chat room, bring it up on meta, or downvote the answer and move on.
- **It's slow.** But then, so is any form of community review.

Bounties tend to drive views from users looking for some kind of reward, whether it be the challenge of solving a tough problem or just a reputation boost. Questions that would have this sort of bounty offered were probably solved a long time ago by someone else. They don't offer much of a challenge and existing answers are probably already upvoted. Editing an old, high-quality answer doesn't get you any rep. Downvoting an out-of-date answer *costs* you rep, and in the face of a particularly highly-scoring answer, may seem futile.

### So, what?

Despite all its problems, I think this bounty option has **some amount of utility** at present for adding a little "oomph" to your comment, downvote, meta post and/or chat discussion about obsolete answers. We know that it increases views on a question, which is a basic requirement for any community action, and it's functional *right now*. It's often better to improve an existing feature than to add a new one; consider giving this one a try.

Comment: 5 years on this site and somehow this option has escaped my notice. It needs more publicity.

Comment: @Basic If awareness were the only problem, it could make sense to add an option to the flag dialogue that *redirects* the user to offer a bounty for revision of outdated answers. But with the current bounty system, neither the user who *identifies* the need for revision nor the user who *performs* it would necessarily be rewarded.

Comment: Yes, and someone who [potentially] hasn't done anything to improve the situation gets a bounty awarded to them.

Comment: BTW I used the wrong word. The "flag" I described indeed was for community, not moderators. I have since edited my post and replaced the word "falg" with "vote". Hope that clears it up. But I have to agree that you have a point here.

Comment: +1 because of all the approaches that are known to me, bounties are easiest to associate with the keyword **goodwill**. Context:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261875/166799 under *How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?*

Answer (score 22):

This is all triggered by a misreading of the situation. The question that caused all the fuss is a classic example of why resource/poll/list questions are off-topic. The answers get old and useless. Instead of worrying about the fact that some of the answers to this question have suffered the inevitable fate of those answers, the solution would be to close (and probably delete) this question.

If anyone could show a significant volume of decent answers to on-topic questions that had aged poorly, and could not be addressed by voting and editing, then we might have something to discuss.

Comment: Mmm not quite delete, but close, yet. What if the code is for legacy browsers or something where it's obsolete for modern times, but relevant for those who still develop for legacy support?

Comment: Unless they're properly qualified, almost any answer can become "old and useless".

Comment: Worse than aged, there are [examples](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311425/many-answers-in-android-camera-are-spreading-a-lie) (not a significant volume, luckily) that were plagued from day 1.

Answer (score 20):

I think there might be an easier way to address most cases where this occurs: don't make accept votes automatically pin answers to the top.

In the majority of cases where I've seen people complaining about an obsolete or no longer correct answer, it was the accepted answer and it had fewer total votes than better or more modern answers. The person who had asked the question and accepted the answer had long since gone inactive, so it was never going to change. Therefore, it remained pinned at the top of the list of answers.

I strongly believe that we should stop treating accept votes as special cases for sorting, and should at best be using them as tiebreakers on equally-voted answers. I think this would help expose better answers, and would prevent unnatural attention being brought to particular answers simply due to the opinion of one person at one point in time.

Users would still get the additional reputation for having an accepted answer, and the accepted answer would still be clearly indicated by the green checkmark. I just don't believe one person's opinion should overrule community voting.

Yes, we'll still have highly voted obsolete answers in the mix, but this is a simple change that could be made today without adding this whole other obsolescence system and the oversight it would require.

Comment: Alternatively, allow the pinned status of an accepted answer to "expire" after a certain amount of time passes.

Comment: I'm definitely a fan of accepted answers not being exempt from sorting. The answer which prompted all this wouldn't actually benefit from this change but I suspect many others would. I tried to get some stats out of SEDE but couldn't optimise enough to avoid timeouts.

Comment: Accepted answer can be deleted (also it needs enough negative votes to start deletion).

Comment: +1 While this answer doesn't answer the question completely, because I don't believe all obsolete/outdated answers are the ones that are accepted, I strongly agree to this _feature modification_ for all given reasons.

Comment: There's a flipside to this, which is that when the One True And Brilliant Answer finally comes along to an old, popular question that is already covered in naff-but-mildly-upvoted answers, a savvy and conscientious asker can use accepting the answer to give it a shortcut to visibility that it otherwise wouldn't receive for months or years. This is clearly a good thing, though perhaps not good enough to outweigh the harm caused by crap or obsolete answers forever being stuck at the top of the page. Is there some cunning way we could keep the good while jettisoning the bad?

Answer (score 11):

> *If this answer were out of date, you could just edit it to put a tag like this on top.*

I like the idea of sticking a box at the top of dangerously outdated answers to warn of that, but I disagree with the need for a dedicated site feature.

We already have a fine edit system, which can be used to place such boxes. Using the existing edit feature is simple, it's flexible (because a relevant custom message can be used, and that can also be easily edited), and it's accountable (because the revision history shows who made the edit and there will probably be comments below discussing it). In the event that the answerer complains about the tag on their post (which is probably unlikely because if they cared about the post they would have listened to the comments complaining that it is outdated) then a mod could do the edit, and maybe lock it. So the edit system can already do everything that is needed.

You say that "people are hesitant to edit someone else's answer" but I'm not convinced that's true because I have sometimes seen, while reviewing suggested edits, edits that attempt to revamp outdated answers or to place ad-hoc tags warning of problems. They are currently rejected as "invalid edits", but all we need to change that is a bit of agreement and written rule for when such edits are appropriate.

Whereas, your proposed feature is more tricky and complex. You've already identified two of the subtleties, such as how many people it should take to attach such a tag and what rep they should have. But also consider: Should there be a review queue to approve/reject these proposed tags? What happens if the tag is placed incorrectly? What if only part of the answer is obsolete? What if the answer is not technically obsolete because it was always bad practice, but people flag it anyway to protest it, and now you have a silly inaccurate tag? What if the answerer comes back and updates/expands their answer? -- Now you have an obsolete obsolescence tag!

I'm also concerned that solidifying this as a software feature would encourage its overuse, because people like clicking buttons and watching stuff happen to make themselves feel useful. The number of answers which meet all the criteria of being (1) dangerously outdated (2) abandoned by their owners (3) highly upvoted and highly visible due to not being pushed down the page by accepted or higher scoring answers, and (4) unfixable through normal edits; and thus which genuinely warrant a warning on top is probably small, and I think they can be dealt with manually quite well, without a dedicated feature.

Comment: I like this approach. Saves the original poster from losing reputation for a (formerly valid) good answer, and maintains the post for posterity, while having a warning to prevent people from wasting their time pursuing something that's no longer valid. I added one to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24951186/3063884

Answer (score 11):

My issue with this is that I don't believe a truly valid answer can *ever* become obsolete.

Sure, it can become outdated but, if the Q&A on-topic guidelines are followed, it will still be valid *in a particular context* (generally in the context of an older version of a particular technology). In that case, the appropriate thing to do is amend the answer to highlight the context.

The example answer is obsolete. The reason that it is obsolete is that it contravenes the site's guidelines that were put in place to *prevent obsolete content*:

- In the case of the answer, link-only answers should be deleted.
- In the case of the question, requests for off-site resources are off-topic.

And this is exactly the reason for both of those guidelines.

The appropriate action in this scenario is to *close the question* or, if that's deemed to be too harsh or the question is deemed useful, *delete or update the answer*.

I struggle to see a scenario in which this feature is really needed. All I see this feature as is a step towards diluting the purpose of the site and promoting rubbish content because if bad content arises, we can always just mark it as obsolete later and leave it sitting there. Adding features that help support the existence of questionable content is not the way to encourage quality.

If the existing content and moderation guidelines for the site are followed properly, this feature has no purpose.

Comment: You raise really valid points. +1 :) But there is always the gray area of usefulness over site guidelines. So these questions stay. And let's be practical and agree that site guidelines will never be "properly" followed :D The other thing is, outdated content is always just sitting there even as we converse. People don't really update others' answers (that's why we have community wiki).

Comment: @Krumia It's true that site guidelines will never always be followed, but that's not a good reason to add features that make it easier not to follow them! And, as I said, if the question is useful but not strictly kosher, there are better ways to improve relevance such as deleting link-only answers or adding context to things that aren't right up-to-date (e.g. "this has been superseded as of version x.y.z.")

Comment: This will be a problem if we "just mark it as obsolete" as you say. But the vote is not for that. It's a warning to vistors as well as an invitation to others to improve the answers. And I'm not sure how this will "help support the existence of questionable content".

Comment: @Krumia Because, as I mentioned, I believe that any valid content will not truly be "obsolete" as long as it is updated with the context in which it is relevant (e.g. older versions of software), so the only real use case for this is to maintain dodgy content that should probably be removed altogether (such as link-only answers to things that don't exist any more). Anything worth having can be corrected with appropriate edits. The edits do not have to be overhauls, just an extra note to say "this is outdated from version x onwards."

Comment: If the problem is people not wanting to step on the toes of answerers, then the solution should be a mechanism to encourage people to edit answers that need more context.

Comment: And you don't think this would encourage people to edit answers?

Comment: I think it's an unnecessary step. If you know the answer is outdated, you have the knowledge to make the appropriate amendments. So we've come full circle - the users of this feature are people who should just be editing the answer or people who should be taking another action such as closing the question or flagging the answer for deletion. If it's the former, I don't see the need for just having a button that effectively says "someone sort this answer out; I don't want to do it." Perhaps what's actually needed is a UI change to encourage people to hit the "edit" button when they should.

Comment: I have to agree. People who identify the problem _are_ most suited to correct it. Except for, as I said, nobody updates others' answers here. So I may have given a solution to non-existent problem.

Comment: IMO, obsoleteness is relevant to the context of the question.  If a question asks about specific versions, then answers regarding those versions will, by definition, never be obsolete.  If a question asks how to do something in general, then answers become obsolete if the method suggested is no longer available and/or safe in recent versions of the topic AND the answer doesn't specify which version it's aimed at.  If the question specifically regards the most recent version of something, then answers become obsolete as new versions are released.  As more efficient ways of doing something

Comment: become available, answers using the older, less efficient ways will become "soft obsolete", for lack of a better term: They still work, but are no longer the best way to do the thing in question.  And so on.

Comment: This doesn't make obsolete answers any less _useful_, however; legacy answers will always be useful, as long as there is still code depending on legacy versions.  So, I guess I agree with you, that nothing is truly obsolete as long as its target version and/or resources are properly documented.

Answer (score 9):

Moderators do not have the technical wherewithal in all tags to determine the technical veracity of an answer.

Simply put, a flag won't help because we don't always know whether it's correct.

Also, there are times an answer is obsolete only when you apply it to the newest version; for earlier versions of software, it may not be obsolete  (That's where Good tagging comes into play).

If you see an answer is way out of date, edit it to include what versions it is applicable to, and when it stopped being applicable (if you know that).  That'll help each individual user ascertain whether the answer applies to them or not.

Comment: George, the proposed flag is _not_ for moderator attention (I should have used some other word). Rather it's for the community. Moderators may not know, but community probably knows. That is why it requires 3 obsolete flags from community to display the message.

Comment: @Krumia So, how do you get "the community" to notice all those flags you want to raise? A review-queue?

Comment: @Deduplicator: The message. That's how community will notice. But the message will require several flags to get activated.

Answer (score 6):

One alternative that may be simpler to implement and solves the problem in a different way is to change the answer sorting algorithm to favor recent votes.

## Example

- A 4 year old obsolete answer has 50 votes, very few of them recent.
- A 2 month old answer has 20 votes, obviously all within the last two months.

Clearly, people are voting that the newer answer is accurate, and the older answer is not, so show the 20-vote answer first and the 50-vote answer second.

Thereafter, people will recognize the 20-vote answer as valid and vote it up faster, while the 50-vote answer still remains for posterity that may need it.

**Update**: I realized this may not necessarily fit as an answer to this question, so I asked this in more detail as a new question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272776/account-for-age-of-votes-in-answer-ordering). I'm leaving this answer here as well in case it is still appropriate.

Comment: The [Wilson score confidence interval](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) as [currently used on Reddit](http://www.redditblog.com/2009/10/reddits-new-comment-sorting-system.html) could help remove the bias toward early answers.

Answer (score -1):

This is a good idea, but I feel it could have a few improvements.  (For a shorter summary of these suggestions, please see the bottom of the post.)

1. The "obsolete" vote could provide a list of generic reasons, such as:

   - **This post is no longer applicable as of version *X*, because *Y*.**  *X* is the relevant version of the language and/or one or more resources used in the post.  *Y* is a short summary of why the post is no longer applicable (and must be entered manually; due to this reason's broadness, no presupplied *Y* s are available to choose from).
   - **There are more efficient ways to do this as of version *X*, such as *Y*.**  *X* is the relevant version of the language and/or one or more resources used in the post.  *Y* is a short summary of one or more ways to do this, and/or the name of one or more language features or resources that can be used for it.
   - **Resource *Q* is no longer updated, as of version *X*; *Y* is instead recommended.**  *Q* is one or more resources used in the post, *X* is the relevant version of said resource(s), and *Y* is an alternative resource that is recommended as a viable alternative, which can be entered via text box or selected from a list; for every *Q*<sub>N</sub> specified, an *X*<sub>N</sub> and *Y*<sub>N</sub> must also be specified.
   - **Language features and/or standard library resources used by this post, *Y*, have been officially deprecated as of version *X*.**  *X* is the relevant version of the language.  *Y* is the name of one or more deprecated feature/resources.
   - **This post is no longer possible as of version *X*, due to breaking change(s) *Y*.**  *X* is the relevant version of the language and/or one or more resources used in the post.  *Y* is a short description of relevant breaking changes.
   - **Other (please specify):**  An empty text box, allowing the voter to give a more specific reason, if none of the standard cases cover it (similar to the OP's mock-up).

   For any of these, *X* can be entered either with a text box, or by selecting a relevant versioning tag if applicable (such as `[c++03]` or `[python-2.7]`).  Similarly, *Q* can be specified either with a text box, or by selecting a relevant tag if applicable (such as `[libpng]` or `[jquery]`).  *Y* can be entered either with a text box, and/or by selecting one or more options from a list (with list entries determined based on the selected reason, and *X* (and *Q*, if applicable); more on this in point #3).  An optional "suggested alternative" box is provided

   This allows greater flexibility in specifying what exactly is obsolete, making it easier to solve the issue and provide a more recent solution.
2. Obsolete-voted posts can be marked as "safe obsolete" or "potentially harmful obsolete" (or perhaps "soft obsolete" and "hard obsolete") by the system.

   - "Safe obsolete" indicates that while obsolete, the answer is still viable; it may no longer be the preferred solution in modern `LanguageInQuestion` or with `ResourceInQuestion`, it may be less efficient than solutions available in newer versions, etc, but it still works.
   - "Potentially harmful obsolete" indicates that the answer no longer works and/or can no longer be safely recommended; it may have been disabled by a breaking change in recent versions, previously-unknown flaws and/or deficiencies may have been exposed/introduced in recent versions, etc.

   This allows the review system to either be weighted towards dangerously obsolete posts, or the two to be given separate queues (so that "potentially harmful" posts don't push "safe" ones out of view).

   [Each obsolete-voted post's category is calculated based on the specified obsolete-vote reason, as well as versioning and/or resource information (if applicable).  If the system can't determine which category an obsolete-voted post fits in, it is instead placed in a third queue, (possibly called something like "uncategorised obsolete" or "may be obsolete"); this queue is intended to get reviewers to supply enough information for it to firmly be placed in one of the categories or have obsolete-votes removed.]
3. For any given tag, that tag can be assigned additional information, which is used to allow the system to categorise obsolete posts; this information will also be part of the tag's wiki entry, if applicable.

   - Resource tags can be classified as "obsolete" (or in more severe cases, "dangerously obsolete"; this requires that one or more reasons that its use can be considered dangerous must be specified), in which case one or more recommended alternatives must be specified; these alternatives are used with obsolete-vote reason "Resource *Q* is no longer updated".  Resource tags should also specify the resource's current version, if multiple versions exist; if no versioning tags are available, this can be specified as a string.  [If multiple significant versions exist, differences and breaking changes between them can be specified, similarly to versioning differences & breaking changes.]
   - Versioning tags can specify new features which are added with that version, and old features which are deprecated.
   - Both resource & versioning tags can specify which version(s) or resource(s) they break compatibility with (for example, `[python-3.x]` can specify that it breaks compatibility with `[python-2.7]`), and/or which version(s) or resource(s) break(s) compatibility with them (conversely, `[python-2.7]` can specify that `[python-3.x]` breaks compatibility with it).  For any given tag *i* that breaks compatibility with tag *j*, *i* can specify how it breaks compatibility.  This information is implicitly propagated; if *i* specifies that it breaks compatibility with *j*, then *j* is automatically updated to indicate that *i* breaks compatibility with it, and vice versa; breaking changes will be listed on *i*, and *j* will provide a link to it for more information.

   This information can be specified as either strings or tags; each implies the relevant other, if applicable (e.g. the string "C++03" implies the tag `[c++03]`, and the tag `[python-2.7]` implies the string "Python 2.7"); this allows version information to be specified for tags which don't provide versioning tags.  For tags marked "obsolete" and/or "breaks compatibility with", the summary can instead be provided as a link to SO Docs or a reliable third-party source (preferably official documentation) describing the required information.  This information, if applicable, is used to generate the list of *Y* options, depending on the obsolete reason chosen.
4. Once a post is obsolete-voted, obsoleteness is determined relevant to the question's relevant version and/or resource tags; if no version is specified for the tag, and one is required, then the most recent official, full version is implied (e.g., as of Dec.5, 2016, the tag `[c++]` would imply the version tag `[c++14]`, but not `[c++1z]`/`[c++17]`).

   - For answers, information supplied in the obsolete-vote is used to determine whether to classify it as "safe" or "potentially harmful".  Answer obsoleteness severity is calculated relative to the question, based on the obsolete-vote's *X* (by tracing a path from it to the question's specified version) and/or *Q* (by checking whether it's obsolete, and if so, whether it counts as *dangerously* obsolete), using the information specified in #3.
   - For questions, obsoleteness is determined by examining the question's versioning and/or resource tags; versioning tags are compared to the language's implied version (which, as previously mentioned, is guaranteed to be the most recent official, full version), and resouce tags are checked for obsoleteness.  If a question uses tags that are considered to be obsolete, it can optionally be marked as a "Legacy" question, to indicate that it specifically deals with obsolete topics; marking a question as "Legacy" also requires that the outdated version(s) and/or resource(s) used in the question be explicitly specified.

     [Marking a question as "Legacy" is intended to differentiate between potentially-relevant questions that mention obsolete topics (such as comparing multiple versions, asking about changes introduced in the tagged version, asking for help with refactoring to use more current resources, etc.), and questions specifically requesting help with obsolete topics.  Marking a question as "Legacy" also indicates to the system that answers are expected to be at least as obsolete as the question itself.]
5. Questions marked as "Legacy" also indicate that not all potential duplicates actually *are* duplicates, if the "Legacy" question's accepted (highest-voted?) answer could be considered "potentially harmful" obsolete based on the new question's tags (e.g. if there are any breaking changes between the "Legacy" question's target version and the new question's target version, or the "Legacy" question is about a "dangerously obsolete" resource and the new question is about one of that resource's suggested alternatives).

   - "Legacy" questions regarding obsolete versions cannot be used as a duplicate source if the "Legacy" question's accepted (highest-voted?) answer could be considered "potentially harmful" obsolete due to the new question using a newer version (e.g. if there are breaking changes somewhere between the "Legacy" question's specified version and the new question's specified or implied version).  [If the flag is auto-declined, the given reason is based on the reason that the answer is considered "potentially harmful" obsolete for the new question.]

     For example, suppose we had language `MyLingo` (tag: `[mylingo]`), with versions 1.0 (no tag), 1.5 (`[mylingo-1.5]`), and 1.6 (`[mylingo-1.6]`); 1.5 is fully backwards-compatible with 1.0, but 1.6 has breaking changes from 1.5.  `MyLingo` supplies feature `foo`, which is a very complex beast; its usage is one of 1.6's breaking changes.  We also have a "Legacy: `MyLingo 1.0`" question, "How do I safely use `foo`?"  The question "How do I use `foo`?" is later asked, after `MyLingo 1.6` has been released, and flagged as a potential duplicate; the system traces a path between `MyLingo 1.0` and the new question, to determine whether this flag is valid.  If the question is tagged with `[mylingo-1.5]`, then the flag goes through; if it's tagged with `[mylingo-1.6]`, or just with `[mylingo]` (which implies `[mylingo-1.6]` for obsoleteness checks), then the flag is automatically declined, as "Breaking changes between `[mylingo-1.5]` and `[mylingo-1.6]` make *How do I safely use `foo`?* 's accepted answer inapplicable for this question."
   - "Legacy" questions regarding obsolete resources cannot be used as a duplicate source if the "Legacy" question's accepted (highest-voted?) answer could be considered "potentially harmful" obsolete due to the new question using newer resources (e.g. if the new question is about a resource that is specified as a suggested alternative to the "Legacy" question's resource).  If the resource's tag has a "current" version specified, and the "Legacy" question uses an outdated version, this can also be used to detect "potentially harmful" obsolete issues related to the version differences, if enough information is supplied on the resource's page.

     For example, suppose we had resource `MyOldLibrary` (`[myoldlib]`), which has versions 1.0 and 1.1 (1.1 has breaking changes from 1.0, regarding feature `bar`); this resource is outdated (1.0 is dangerous because it deletes `%windir%\system128` if a `bar` is obtained on Windows 42 or later, and breaks `/dev/null` if a `bar` is obtained on any version of Linux whose kernel is version `23.4` or higher; 1.1 fixes this issue, but is no longer supported), and resource `MyNewLibrary` (`[mynewlib]`) is recommended as an alternative (and also provides `bar`, albeit slightly differently than `MyOldLibrary`; `MyNewLibrary`, however, also provides a `MyOldLibrary` adapter, which is fully compatible with `MyOldLibrary 1.1`).  We also have a "Legacy: `MyOldLibrary 1.0`" question, "Why am I unable to requisition a thread-safe `bar` that can be used concurrently by multiple threads?"  The question "How do I use a single `bar` for multithreading?" is later asked, after `MyOldLibrary 1.1` was discontinued and `MyNewLibrary` has been released, and flagged as a potential duplicate; the system traces a path between `MyOldLibrary 1.0` and this question, to determine the validity of the flag.  If the question is tagged with `[mynewlib]`, the flag is automatically declined as "This question requests information about `[mynewlib]`, which replaces outdated resource `[myoldlib] 1.0` used in *Why am I unable to requisition a thread-safe `bar` that can be used concurrently by multiple threads?*"; if the question is tagged with `[myoldlib]`, but not `[mynewlib]`, its body and title are parsed for a version number, with the flag being accepted if it determines that the question is about version 1.0, or otherwise declined as "Breaking changes between `[myoldlib] 1.0` and `[myoldlib] 1.1` make *Why am I unable to requisition a thread-safe `bar` that can be used concurrently by multiple threads?* 's accepted answer inapplicable for this question."
6. Questions can also be marked as "Version-Independent" or "Resource-Independent" (this category may need to be renamed).  This indicates that the question is intended to present a list of solutions for all available versions, and/or all related resources, so that it can be used as a duplicate source for any identical questions, regardless of version.  Answers to the question must specify which version(s) and/or resource(s) they're applicable for, and the answers can be filtered to only display results for specified version(s)/resource(s).  Answers from other, related questions can also be merged into a version-independent question, using the version specified by their original question; if their original question didn't specify a version, then the system automatically flags them as "may be obsolete", so reviewers can specify their target version.

   Once a new version is released, or one of the resources used in answers is marked as obsolete, the question is automatically marked as "may be obsolete" by the system, with a custom reason of:

   > "Due to [the release of new version [ver] / resource [res] becoming obsolete], this question might not provide the most up-to-date solution to the problem.  Please determine whether a new answer is required."

This may be going a bit overboard, but I feel that a well-designed "obsoleteness" system could both make it easy to find information relative to specific language versions and/or resources, and make it easier to appropriately determine when a question is a potential duplicate (or conversely, when it's time for a new set of answers).

---

### Summary:

1. Obsolete votes should require the voter to specify why the post is obsolete, providing technical details about which part of the post specifically is obsolete.  Tags or text strings can be used for this.  This can be streamlined with a set of standard reasons, which prompt the voter for the required information.
2. Based on the above information, and information associated with the relevant tags, the system can determine whether a post is "potentially harmful" obsolete, or if it's obsolete but "safe" to use; this is used to categorise obsolete posts for reviewing.  If the system is unable to determine which to classify a post as, it is marked as "may be obsolete", and sent to review for people to supply enough information for the system to classify it.
3. Version and resource tags can be assigned additional information, which is used by the system for determining how to classify obsolete posts.  This information should include obsoleteness severity (whether or not something is "dangerously obsolete"), changes introduced by new versions, a list of breaking changes in each version (if applicable), and recommended alternatives for obsolete resources (if applicable).  If a resource has multiple versions, but no version tags, version information is assigned to the resource's tag instead.
4. The obsoleteness of obsolete-version posts is determined relevant to the question's version and/or resource tags; if the question doesn't specify a version, and the post is obsolete because of new versions, then the question is assumed to be about the most recent official, full version.  [If a question is obsolete, it can be marked as a "Legacy" question, which indicates that it's aimed specifically at obsolete versions and/or resources.]
5. "Legacy" questions can only be used as duplicate sources if their accepted (highest-voted?) answer(s) would only be considered "safe obsolete" compared to the potential duplicate's tags.  If the answers would be "potentially harmful obsolete", then the duplicate flag is automatically declined, with the system indicating that the "Legacy" question's accepted (highest-voted?) answer is inapplicable for the new question (and using obsoleteness information to describe *why* it's inapplicable).
6. Questions can also be marked as "Version-Independent" or "Resource-Independent", to indicate that they're intended to collect answers relevant to *every* version and/or resource, both obsolete and current; answers must indicate which version or resource they're aimed at.  These questions are intended to be used as duplicate sources for all potential duplicates, and can be filtered to display answers about specific version(s)/resource(s).  [These questions are automatically marked as "may be obsolete" when a new version is released or a used resource becomes obsolete, to ensure that a new, more up-to-date answer will be added if necessary.]

Comment: Try to avoid posting a wall of text please.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Sorry, but not all replies can be, say, 5000 characters or less, especially if they attempt to significantly flesh an idea out in a clear, easily-understandable manner.  I did add a short summary at the bottom, however, and added a note at the top to indicate that it was there.  Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately, your summary is still a wall of text. It would be better if there was a tl;dr version at the top.

Comment: @StephenLeppik I didn't know that 2,920 characters counted as a "wall of text"; note that it's only a bit longer than [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272715/5386374) (which appears to be 2,602 characters), but no one complained about _it_ being a "wall of text".  Also note that there's no rule against long posts; if there was, the character limit would be _much_ less than 30,000.  While the summary isn't just a single sentence for each point, that doesn't automatically make it too long; removing anything else from it would be more detrimental than leaving it as it is.

Comment: Basically, if the choice is between accurate but verbose, or terse but inaccurate, then the former is, IMO, _always_ the better option unless you're explicitly required to choose the latter.

Comment: Also note that [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272691/5386374) is _longer_ than my summary.  As with the other, nobody complained that it was too long.

Comment: Wall-of-text doesn't mean "super long", it means "long winded and difficult to get through the first few paragraphs".

Comment: @StephenLeppik Out of curiosity, what makes the summary difficult to get through, other than actually being long enough to accurately sum up the main body?

Answer (score -1):

### New Question

The current question would probably be directed towards either a version (especially on Stack Overflow, ex. Python) so someone could just ask a new question when the information is needed.

### New Answer

Just make a new answer.

### Split the new answer by using the magical line separator (`---`)

> ---

### "If _____, do this:"

Say something that tells you to do something other that was is previous explained if your version is ______.

> If you are using version 1.3.7, you must use `newFunc();` as `oldFunc();` has been removed.

Answer (score -2):

While it sounds like a great dream to have, it would actually be a nightmare. For example, just think of all the jQuery questions which may not of specified a particular version in the question or its tags. Think about people having to go back and edit all these with what they think the version is that the questioner was using. Think about people falsely marking answers as obsolete even though people still use the old versions of the library. This applies to like almost every language and there are so many other factors like browsers and their own versions, and plugins and frameworks, etc.

All of our review queues are non-expert queues. Meaning that you don't need to be in expert in the tag to tell if the question may need to be closed, or if the edit should be approved, or if the answer is likely junk that should be deleted... This would be moderating the technical accuracies of the content itself. We do this by giving up and downvotes. The accepted answer is just whatever the questioner chose to accept.  While it's normally the best answer, it may not even be helpful at all.

**If you know enough that the answer is outdated. Just leave your own answer and leave a comment under the other answer explaining it's outdated.**

Simple as that. Having a flag for this is ridiculous since no one is an expert or even a moderate in every tag, and by having a flag for this you'd be assuming that ~15 moderators are experts on everything. Why have an obsolete flag, when moderators wouldn't be able to act on a majority of them? Why waste all the time sending these supposed outdated posts to a review queue, when you could just leave a comment that it's outdated in 2 seconds? And leave your own answer within 2-20 minutes?

Comment: "Just leave your own answer and leave a comment" That is my first suggestion. But the problem is, these comments/answers are not really visible. It takes an enormous amount of time for the question to get downvoted or the comment to get upvoted to visibility. Especially when there's a penalty on downvoting answers. This proposal is not about _updating_ obsolete answers, rather, it's about _identifying_ obsolete answers.

Comment: And how about the current flags? Does these 15 moderators have enough domain knowledge to decide if every question posted is on-topic? And the proposed flag is _not_ for moderators. Rather, it is a mere signal to the community.

Comment: @Krumia if it's obsolete, then the people looking for help on it will notice this, and hopefully check the other answers for the right solution. Like I said, it's great in theory, but would cause more headaches and fights than it's worth.

Comment: The people looking for help will first try out the accepted and highly upvoted answer. And waste time.

Comment: @Krumia Yea, moderators don't know enough to be able to close or not close every single question that hits the close queue.. but a good majority of them they do. This obsolete queue would change that number from like 75% to like 15% or less.

Comment: And again, you're missing the point. I can comment in two seconds, I can write an answer in 2-20 minutes, and nobody is going to see them on the swarm of upvoted answers and comments.

Comment: @Krumia, yes that is the worst thing; that a better Answer is 'hidden' (we must read the whole Page twice). Perhaps the Answers could be 'preferentially ordered' by BOTH "having received more than 3 VoteUps" AND "the Recency/Trending of the VoteUps". Then Answers with few VoteUps that were recently adopted by the Community as a 'better' Answer (a "Trending Answer") would be first (with the relatively few Votes predominantly shown). Following the "Trending Answer" would be the "Most Voted Answers". Combined that with Versioning and Forking for maximum power and all round good fun.

Answer (score -2):

You propose an “Obsolete Answer Flag" for "hugely upvoted, bad answers", to 'punish' the Answer because it was (at one time, possibly still) Favorited by many. Is it not the upvotes which are the greatest fault and not the answer once so favored that 'needs' the discredit.

This Flag will need to serve more than one purpose to make the most use out of it, in other comments here people have proposed that it also take care of "difference between answers that are valid for an older version of a language ..." and other comments about not needing another Flag (or more work to figure out).

Perhaps rather than a straight accept vs. reject we could have "Versioning" and "Forking" of the Answers **IF** the Moderator decides it is appropriate for the Question.

For example: someone might ask how to do something on their Computer, and in which particular Computer Language would such a Program be most efficiently written. There could be two or more "best" answers, each with a huge number of followers.

In the other case the "old" Answer could still be good for some years to come but to bury the "new" answer NEAR the bottom (due to so few upvotes but not the least) does the "better" Answer a disservice.

Indeed the so-called best Answer, for the person who asked the Question, might well be the old Answer but the **better** Answer for most everyone else (just starting out, or using newer Software) in either a new and improved method, or one that is now required due to a change in the Software.

In another case one Answer may only apply to people with long arms, and if you have short arms then the other answer is much better.

Use of "Versioning" and "Forking" in the traditional manner (as it applies to Software) is likely an easy way to deal with Q&A's that are to be made more complex than was initially planned.

It is also likely to be something doable using this Site's Software. Cost of implementation, ease of use, and resulting questions or complaints afterwards are something to be factored into the design and cost analysis.

Comment: I really don't see a "punishment" here. Reputation is just imaginary internet points. The primary point of these points is to find better answers, not to reward individuals. The individual got upvotes for his effort at one time, which is good. But if he is too lazy to update it, people will see the answer getting outdated and downvote it, with or without the proposed "obsolete" vote.

Comment: Your idea of "forking" is great. I interpret it as copying the old answer, improving it and posting it as my own answer. But people generally see this as plagiarism. And then there is the problem of this new answer getting burried in the swarm of hugely upvoted answers. And we're back to square one.

Comment: Both "Versioning" and "Forking", IE: an "Improvement" vs. a "ReWrite". That allows 'credit' for the old answer (which may have use to some) to remain with the individual that deserves it (we, or I, judge Answers on Rep., and common sense) so I don't want helpful people to lose their Rep. (or be tied to every Post they ever made on the Internet, and be obligated to keep them up to date). -- The "copying the old answer" as you call it would not be "plagiarism" IF credit was given (Links on both Pages) and the alternate Versions and Forks could appear in a Panel in the right-side Column.