# A dupe to question with obsolete/soon to be obsolete answers.

Tags: discussion

I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179946/dummy-non-pre-declarable-variable-for-out?noredirect=1#comment41047594_26179946) that was marked as a dupe. Indeed, as I check out the reference, the question **is** answered. However, the answer is aged and one of the commenters to my question implies that there'll be changes (or perhaps even already are) that will render my question (as well as the other) incorrectly answered.

How should I treat this situation?

Comment: I've changed title that I think reflects your concern. If don't like the change please *try* to come up with less confusing text than original one before reverting.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Me likie! Much better this way.

Answer (score 2):

You may be overthinking this – it looks like a straightforward case of a duplicate question to me.

That's not to say it's useless; yours is tagged [out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/out) (yuck) and [output-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/output-parameter) while the other is tagged [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) and [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net), so they'll appear differently in search results. Your title also uses words that the other title doesn't, and vice-versa.

When standards or implementations change, lots of answers become obsolete. I would wager that there are far larger chains of duplicates on the site that will collectively become obsolete within the next year. That doesn't stop them from being duplicates.

Comment: I realize that the tags should read *C#6* and *C#<6* to discriminate between them. If two OPs ask "*how to compare strings?*" and the tags are *Java* and *C#* respectively, that's not a dupe, despite of the same **wording**. (It's *Equal()* and "*==*" respectively.) It becomes less clear with different version of a framework - I'm not certain how to handle **that** difference. (E.g. "*can I use lambda expressions?*" is answered "*no*" **and** "*yes*" depending on the tagification.)

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate to question with obsolete answer is still duplicate.

There is very simple fix for "aged" answers - add new one or even update existing one.

Most problems will not magically disappear over time (i.e. there is no way `out` parameters will completely disappear from C# in foreseeable future) - so if you find your (or someone else) question to be marked as proper duplicate of some question with old answers you can add new one there.

Comment: There is somewhat related discussion on ["Obsolete answer feature"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272651/introduce-an-obsolete-answer-vote) that covers dealing with such answers.

Comment: ... And it's fully possible that the OP doesn't even bother checking the new addition. Moreover - how are we supposed to update the incomplete answers if nobody actually asks (and doesn't get closed down) the "same" question? Plus we have that rep-thingy. (Yes, I **do** want my rep to grow and I'm not ashamed to admit it.) All in all, I'd like to propose that those question are **different** (even if they're phrased in the same way and target the same area) with the degree of freedom based on the version of the framework (date?) and not on the contents of the post.