# Credit to original poster when future answers rely heavily on original solution

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Scenario:

- Poster A posts answer.
- Poster B copies answer A, makes small improvements, and re-posts.
- Subsequent users give credit to Poster B.

If both answers weigh relatively equally, and B is an improvement, then this outcome perhaps makes some sense.

Consider this scenario however:

- Answer A is very elaborate, very lengthy, of very high quality, not obvious, or solves the problem in a unique, very efficient, or clever way. Or some combination of this.
- Answer B offers a relatively small improvement on an otherwise elegantly working solution. Or perhaps it was added later, after an API change that required a small adjustment.
- Answer B likely depends on Answer A, and without it it wouldn't have been posted in the first place.

In that case, it makes no sense that poster B takes the credit. We need a mechanism whereby credit is awarded fairly, to incentive those Posters who put a lot of effort in high quality answers. Perhaps Answer B should show in the UI as an extension of Answer A with correct credit distribution. If that is too difficult to judge/develop, perhaps a moderator can update the original answer with the improvement.

And an easy way to do that: add simple functionality to let new posters 'link' their answer to an original answer. Something like a 'derived from' field. Then when they get a vote, add one to the original answer too.

Example: [Store NSDictionary in keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948698/store-nsdictionary-in-keychain/20649567#20649567).

Comment: So an upvote would be doubled? That seems very difficult to protect from abuse. And what if I couple my answer with yours and we start getting downvotes?

Comment: Ya that would be a problem. I'm not offering a complete solution, just reporting a problem that I think is important. The platform stakeholders can brainstorm and figure out what's the best way to resolve.

Comment: If you asking for discussion you should mark your post "discussion", not "feature-request".

Comment: Side note: please check out "highly upvoted obsolete answers" - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272651/introduce-an-obsolete-answer-vote (and linked discussion) for problem that is currently solved by exact behavior you trying to prevent.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good idea, I added the "discussion" tag as well.

Comment: There is such a mechanism, just post a link, if the original post is helpful likely it will be upvoted and award credit.

Answer (score 6):

A process to achieve this kind of "fairness" would be super subjective, insanely complex, and require moderators to have detailed domain knowledge so they can determine what is derived from what. (Plus this would take an inordinate amount of moderator time.)

There's no way this would work - nor is it, I would argue, really that important.

Yes, occasionally someone who provides answer B may unfairly gain more upvotes than the original author of answer A. However, this is not extremely common - in the long run, it's usually the great, detailed, lengthy answers that win out - and reputation is a very *rough* measure of things anyway: during your SO career, you will be in situations where you unfairly gain too little reputation, and in others where you unfairly gain too much.

A hat tip inside the question, mentioning the author of the original answer, really is the polite thing to do, and it should be enough.

I don't think we need anything beyond that.

Comment: while it may be uncommon for 90% of the users, you have another 10% of perfectionists who systematically put a lot of effort into things, including contributions here. These quality answers pull this platform up and give it extra value. I disagree that it is not important to reward these people, reputation is perhaps the only reason why an expert would put so much effort into something that doesn't otherwise have a monetary gain. I do agree that what I propose above is not easy to design, but that doesn't mean that it's not worth improving the platform in this area.

Comment: @DTs I don't believe there is a *class* of users to whom this happens all the time. I'd much rather think it is something that happens to *all* the active users who make high quality contributions, *some* of the time (but very rarely really).

Comment: Personally I see it all the time, every day actually. I don't think it is a rare case at all. Sometimes the outcome is so heavy that it really breaks down the incentive dynamics of the platform. Check out this thread for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/checkout-remote-git-branch, where user halls simply copied user's Jakub Narębski's answer and over time ended up with 3075!!! more upvotes, which will continue growing as hallski's answer now sits higher up the page.

Comment: @DTs it's the other way round there, though: Jakub built on hallski's answer, and hallski was perfectly fine with it (given that he's actually linking to the new answer).

Comment: You have the same problem in the real world: scientist x reads the huge work of scientist y, builds on it, gets a huge grant. In theory, maybe x should give a part of the grant to y, but in practice, as far as I know, that rarely happens. It's exceedingly difficult to impossible to achieve mathematical "justice" here.

Comment: I don't think this is what happened, if you look more carefully, hallski provided an original answer, Jakub later provided a better and independent answer that had nothing to do with hallski's. Then hallski copied Jakub exactly and offered it as an update on his answer, offering in fact no improvements on it, and effectively rendering the previous version of his answer obsolete. Yes, he did reference Jakub as source, but so what, he still ended up with 3075 more votes.

Comment: Your example about scientists actually reenforces the case in my original posting: the derived work must carry it’s own weight and must improve materially the original work referenced. If not, the new work is not an event in the scientific community, it is rather a ‘replication’ with no reputation attached to it. It is one thing to say, yes this is happening but I haven’t figured out how to solve it on StackOverflow, and quite another to try argue that this is ok. In the latter case, it will never be solved and the platform will not be improved.

Comment: @DTs I see your point. The edit wasn't made by hallski, though, but by another user, probably because the post was accepted and hence at the top of the list. It was also made five years after hallski posted his answer. How many of the 3075 votes were gained *after* that point is impossible to tell but I'm sure it wasn't a majority. How many votes can be referenced to Jakub's answer being copied in there is impossible to measure. The case illustrates why I think it's not a problem that can be solved in a reasonable, rule-based´ way; it's better to live with it. We'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: I'm just planting a seed here, hoping that once people become aware of the problem they'll start noticing it more and more, until we reach a tipping point that enough users decide that this is unfair and that we should do something about it to emulate that academic environment that you referenced.

Comment: Well, as said, we'll have to agree to disagree. To me, there are unfairnesses in the system that are orders of magnitude bigger than what you are describing - complex, well thought out answers to difficult questions generally gain a *lot* less rep than a jQuery one-liner answering a trivial question for example, thanks to the [bike shed effect.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality) *That* would be a problem actually worth tackling, IMO. This one is not.

Comment: Ya that's another one, but I'll leave that one for you to promote. I'll just try to prop this one here :)