# Is there a way to filter out old or beta answers?

Tags: support

Stack Overflow is beginning to lose value because of the amount of information that comes up in a search that is for old, outdated, often beta-version answers.  In my case, this is specifically  related to Angular 2.  If I have to read through one more search result that references Beta.x or RC.0 information, I'm going to have a conniption.

At the time, these questions/answers had value (and most of them have up-voted & accepted answers) but now they are just noise.  Is there some way to filter these out when I search, or can they be downplayed in the results somehow by the system automagically?

Comment: Related:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272651/1079354 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272651/introduce-an-obsolete-answer-vote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there some way to filter these out when I search, or can they be downplayed in the results somehow by the system automagically?

**Yes.** Hit the "active" tab to sort questions so that the ones with recent activity appear at the top. Sorting by "active" means that newer questions will sort higher in the list, but old ones will too if they've seen any recent activity, i.e. editing or new answers. Or, if you really want the *newest* answers, there's also a "newest" tab for filtering search results.

There's an "active" tab in the list of answers for each question, too, so that newer answers and newly edited answers sort higher than old ones.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I often end up coming into SO from Google/Bing so don't see that page, but can change my habit to begin my search on SO and use those tabs.  Thanks.

Comment: that isn't good enough, have a look a this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696499/meta-charset-utf-8-vs-meta-http-equiv-content-type?answertab=active#tab-top the first answer showing is NOT even close to up-to-date :( imagine there are three or four pages, and users keep commenting on first page? the only way to get to new answers is to sort by Oldest and work backward

Comment: @Ayyash It's true that new answers have a hard time getting noticed when there are already many existing answers. But it's also true that 9-year-old questions probably aren't the best source for the most up to date information. When you search for questions on SO, consider filtering by "newest" to prioritize recent questions. Also: if a question has several pages of answers, that's often a sign that none of them are definitive, and that's another reason to either look for better sources or dig in, read a number of answers, and form your own opinion.

Comment: @Caleb search on SO? that's even worse :) i google, and that's what I believe the majority do

Answer (score 7):

If you want the more recent answers at the top in an old question, **it is on you to make that happen.** Vote up the current answers and vote down the outdated ones. Seek attention from your peers so that they can help with this. Seek out the question author so that they can accept a new answer. Edit the answers to note that they're outdated.

Comment: In general, this is correct. In the specific case of Angular, there's even more you can do. Retag any old questions with the [`angularjs`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info) tag, which is for questions about AngularJS (1.x). Newer questions about Angular 2 should be tagged [`angular`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular).

Comment: @BilltheLizard, the "old" questions are still Angular 2, they're just beta and RC so no longer relevant.  Retagging them would not be appropriate.  Thanks, though.

Comment: @StephenLeppik, pretty unrealistic answer there...no way 1 person is going to clean all of this up.  Too, the question often is about things that don't exist anymore as Angular has changed, so the answers are relevant to the question, the question was relevant at the time, but neither of those is true now.  Caleb's answer below is what I was looking for.

Comment: @David It's realistic in the sense that whenever you find an old question with updated answers you can upvote those and downvote the ones that don't work anymore. As time goes by, some balance is achieved.

Comment: @brasofilo: based on the number of outdated questions/answers, either no one is doing this, or it takes too long to achieve any meaningful balance.  Too, they may not work for me using v4 or v5, but if someone is still using RC0 or more realistically 2.0 then it is totally relevant to them.

Comment: @David Well, when I'm writing something, my first help spot is SO, and I always vote up if useful and down if not.

Comment: @David well, you can start by posting in chat rooms.