# Totally different solution from the old answer is added to another old answer

Tags: discussion, behavior

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25532027/7862821) answer had solution to use `parallel` and it was created on Aug 27 '14. Some time later I provided a totally new [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46611168/7862821) to use `xargs` and I did it on Oct 6 '17. Now I see that above answer about `parallel` was updated with my solution (edited Jan 3 '20) to use `xargs` which is definitely another solution which had been already there for a long time.

My question here: is it a proper way to behave like this on Stack Overflow? To take someone's old answer with another solution and add it to his/her answer later?

Comment: I don't really think the user "took" your answer. Seems they just updated and expanded greatly upon both their own solution and your own. Your answer is really just a line of code, while the other one explains *why* choose one over another and shows both approaches. It's not at all guaranteed the author "took" your solution as it's not an exact copy paste. It happens to look similar because it achieves the same effect. So, counter question - should people *not* be allowed to edit and improve their answers, if they happen to slightly overlap with another one?

Comment: The thing is that it's not a slightly overlapping. My answer is not just a line of code, it has all the information: "You can use xargs which supports running many processes at a time". And now the author from TOP answer (because it's older) with another solution writes about the same: "xargs is now the recommended tool to achieve parallel execution and so on". I think we cannot add another solution to our answer if it's already there in answers. Otherwise everyone can add other solutions to their TOP answer and change words about them.

Comment: "*I think we cannot add another solution to our answer if it's already there in answers*" where does it say that?

Comment: Also, if answers cannot be edited, why is the platform allowing it? Surely, they could be editable for, say, 24 hours and then locked forever. Yet that's not what happens, thus allowing edits forever.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Comment: @VLAZ This question is not about editing feature, it's mostly about Stack Overflow etiquette. If the owner of TOP answer adds another solutions to his/her answer, those solutions will be useless and won't get any upvotes anymore, because everyone finds them in the TOP answer. But the thing, that those solutions had been already there for a long time...

Comment: And yet their line is not an exact copy of yours so why can't we conclude they found this on their own. That's the most charitable and indeed likely conclusion.

Comment: @RobertLongson Just look to the timeline of their answer: "Jan 3 at 12:00  history  edited  Manuel Riel  Use xargs instead of parallel". And yet when the answer about `xargs` had been there since October 2017. They could find a better solution by their own, but should have considered that it was already provided 2 years ago.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see any bad intent and the edit overall aligns with SO goals to provide most up to date answers to visitors.

First concern: why user did not "steal" content as soon as you posted an answer - most answerers don't monitor posts they provided answer on. It also requires effort to incorporate more idea/answers into once post. And many people actually and not actively trying to "steal" other answers.

Second concern: why user eventually updated they answer with alternative that matches your answer - something forced them to look at that answer. Maybe it was comment like "you are complete @#$@ by not providing the xargs solution and depriving visitors of an ideal answer", or maybe someone downvoted the answer, or there was an edit, or (which happened to me couple times) author needed an answer to similar question and found they own post... In any case something made them to look at the answer and add another solution. Note that after 6 years they very well may just know that other solution and provided it without looking at your post - searching for duplicates is not rewarded in any way on SO making it better to just answer/update post than even look at other answers.

Whether it is by the site rules/spirit:

- there are no rules that prohibit users to know and provide answers that have same/similar ideas as other answers. Straight plagiarism is indeed prohibited - you are welcome to flag for moderator attention if you find one (I don't think this is the case here, but I'm not a Bash expert).
- it is long standing problem that with technology changes old highly upvoted (or accepted) solutions are not longer "the way" to solve any particular problem. There is no universal solution found so far - casting downvotes on obsolete question is an approach suggested. Without some ideas and work from the SE the only option each individual author of such "correct but obsolete, popular answer" is to keep answer up to date with periodical edits - which I believe what happened in this case. Searching for ["obsolete"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=obsolete) will give you a lot of discussions on this topic including [Introduce an "Obsolete Answer" vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272651/introduce-an-obsolete-answer-vote).

Alternative approaches if you plan to make similar update to accepted/highest voted answer of your own:

- just type up information you know without looking around. If you are expert in that area it is pretty much guaranteed that you can easily do that faster than doing research.
- search for duplicates - there is a good chance that there is similar question with a new answer.
- link to an existing answer. Note you still need to provide summary of the link which in many cases pretty much provides "answer" portion of the answer and only people who need an explanation would visit (and possibly upvote) linked answer
- flat out delete your answer. This may be useful if current "the right way" answer is right after to yours when sorted by votes. If currently recommended answer is 10th in the list deleting your own answer is likely cause confusion.