# Dealing with posts with an outdated accepted answer

Tags: discussion, flags, moderators, outdated-information

I have come across some posts (related to Jdbc) in this forum that have answers that are outdated due to the future driver versions either changing the way things worked or phasing out(depricated) certain methods.

What also complicates things is the person asking the question or members who have answered the question have not provided versions number of tools/products they are using.

How does one deal with such posts. Is there a way to flag them as outdated/obsolete or request for review by the moderators ? The reason i bring this up is , for some one researching an issue such posts may be misleading.

Comment: Moderators can't do much about it anyway. Editing is something every user can already do. Deleting it is certainly not appropriate since it still contains useful information (nor is it fair to the users involved). Locking and post notices are for more serious things like rule-infractions (nor does it solve the problem). And moderators cannot change votes, including the accept mark.

Comment: Or *maybe* this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272570/how-to-deal-with-hugely-upvoted-bad-and-outdated-answers Or even this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267018/promoting-new-answers-to-old-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not flag outdated questions/answers for moderator attention. Do not assume that the moderators have the domain-specific knowledge necessary to act on those flags. Moderators are supposed to be janitors of the system. They're supposed to act on the more obvious clean-ups, and they have too much work already, so we're supposed to call them in only if moderator privileges are absolutely necessary.

If an answer stops being useful, the best way to publicize that fact is to post a comment saying so. If you can specify the exact version number where an answer stops being useful, that's all the better. Edit the answer if you can, or at the very least include that version information in a comment. Or better still, if you know the answer for the new version, you could post that as a new answer, or perhaps you could even consolidate both the old answer and the new answer in the original answer that got accepted.

However, do not attempt to close such questions. Some corporate environments can be stuck on very old legacy systems. And an answer that's not useful to you doesn't mean that it won't be useful to someone else who is stuck on such a system.

And yes, old outdated questions can accumulate lots of points, making them more visible overall, but note that search engines will try to prioritize their search results based on the freshness of the answers given.  And if nothing else, the readers may look at the time stamps of the posts and comments to try to ascertain if an answer is still useful.