# How to ask for help forming a question

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm ultimately trying to re-ask an old question ([Developer specific app config web config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707749/developer-specific-app-config-web-config-files-in-visual-studio)), which is a) out of date and b) I've already tried all answers listed there applicable to me but without satisfactory resolution.

Now following best practices when asking a question on SO, I've sought guidance in how to best approach [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267018/promoting-new-answers-to-old-questions). If I have an answer that I think is worthy for the question, I could start a bounty on it. That's still an option, I could start one but there's a bit more context I'd like to add such as options I've tried that aren't mentioned in the original post (e.g. the SlowCheetah extension which implements the XML transform answer in the old OP).

I could also edit the original question but this doesn't lend itself well to what I've tried in my current situation for VS versions up to 2017. My next thought would be maybe ask for advice on meta.SO on how to format my question with a sample already drafted up...but then I stopped as I had no idea if *that* was a good idea either. I couldn't find any similar examples on meta.SO and little guidance in this respect either. I could also envision meta users getting a little annoyed with what might be perceived as "It's not my job to write your question for you", and not unreasonably.

I now seem to be left with a meta-meta.SO question - how do I ask for guidance on meta to ask a question on SO without attracting Duplicate/Close flags like moths to a flame? Or am I just way overthinking this and should just post the original question on SO and take the downvotes/duplicate/close flags if they happen (and I'm 90+% sure they will)? I don't want to waste my/anyone else's time in a useless question that'll probably get ignored.

Comment: It is not out of date.  Yes, not liking the solutions is pretty common.  At least it isn't as bad as not understanding the solutions, another reason why lots of unnecessary questions get asked.   Satisfaction is not a guarantee and never a good reason to just ask the question again.

Comment: Agreed, in my situation it's not quite a case of "not liking" so much as I've actually tried the suggested answers and found them wanting when it comes down to running a team - they simply don't work very well in a situation where there are frequent new projects with developer teams of varying size and re-use (lots of reasons for that but that's what we have). This lack of consistency between team members and frequent project setups leaves a fairly specific requirement for us not addressed in the original question - hence the question here in how best to form a new question, if at all.

Comment: As for "Out of date", it is in the sense that it doesn't suggest or mention more recent tooling or extensions that may help address the originally posed issue, such as SlowCheetah. I can appreciate this getting subjective though.

Comment: You want to re-ask a question that got closed as non-constructive? Where's the logic to that?

Comment: @yivi, well as the comments and indeed, BilltheLizard suggested, the question relates to a problem most developers face. In my situation, I've already attempted implementing the suggested answers over the years but none have readily/fully addressed the issue. I'm inclined to go with Bill's suggestion and ask on the Software Engineering SE site as he's right, this isn't a specific code problem and more general software/engineering/configuration issue. There is value in asking, just not necessarily on SO - and part of the reason for this question was to determine that

Comment: Must you ask the question on a Stack Exchange site I wonder? Is there no other place on the gigantic web that might be of assistance? Like a developer discussion forum more tailored to the tooling you're involved with?

Comment: @Gimby there absolutely are other sites out there. However SO and the SE network in general is generally the go-to, particularly for programming and software engineering related questions, among others. It would make sense to at least *try* and ask here first, and if not appropriate, ask elsewhere. This question essentially boils down to "Is it appropriate to be asking here?". If not, well, I have my answer :)

Comment: "How you store configuration: discuss" kind of question is not on-topic for SO mainly because it is way too broad (as already indicated by closure of the original one).

Comment: It seems like there's concensus. A question like this is not appropriate for SO and should be taken elsewhere. Thanks for everyone's feedback, I'm glad I asked before doing something foolish!

Comment: @DiskJunky that's just it - that "Stack Overflow is the goto" attitude is why people butt heads with the very pedantic rules of the site which exclude a large proportion of the questions you might want to ask there. But people don't give up, they somehow *must* ask their question there. That's your choice, when you're 90% sure that the question won't be well received, I would flock to another site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd worry less about your question being closed as a duplicate and more about it being closed as not constructive, as the one you linked to was. What's being discussed on that post is more of a standards and best practices issue than a problem with a specific piece of code.

It's definitely a problem that a lot of (probably most) developers face at some point, though, so I'd look around on the [Software Engineering site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) to see if that kind of question would be on-topic there. If you're not sure, you could ask on their Meta site.