# Accepting and promoting new answer to an old question

Tags: discussion, answers, old-questions, old-answers, outdated-information

I've written new answer to very old question because old answers were using old technologies which will soon be unsupported.

How can I promote it to become more popular and accepted? I read [Promoting new answers to old questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267018/promoting-new-answers-to-old-questions) but I dont't want to set bounty because I don't want to spend on reputation.

My answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/52881595/6523409.

Comment: @yivi Who can accept the answer? Only question author or also some moderatiors?

Comment: Given that the question already has an accepted answer with 74 upvotes, from eight years ago, you should not expect to have your answer marked as accepted.  It is useful to add updated answers to old questions, as you have done here, and hopefully your answer will gain upvotes over time.

Comment: Protip: You're probably going to get downvotes on this Meta-Q because it feels like self-promotion (and possibly some on your answer due to the so-called "meta-effect"). You can avoid that and simultaneously improve your question for future users by removing the link to your own work, and either substituting another example that isn't your work, or removing it altogether by making it about the more general process.

Comment: Votes in meta do not affect your rep in any way, though. And I wouldn't discount the meta effect to be beneficial this time. Although I haven't voted nor looked much at the answer myself.

Comment: 50 rep bounty can do wonders, that said. You may get back your "investment" and slightly more

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre The problem is that I can only set 100 or 150 reputation for bounty, which is too high for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Only the question author, no one else.**

This is an eight years old question (and its author hasn't been around for about 4 years). It is not realistic to expect the question asker chooses to change their accepted answer at this time. When they asked the question, the answer they found most helpful is the one they chose.

Votes are more important to determine an answer's quality and usefulness than acceptance anyway. If your answer is good, and the question gets traffic, it's very likely that with time it will be voted up as its quality is recognized by other users.

If you do not want to spend your hard earned rep to set a bounty, you have very little options to attract aditional attention to the question. By answering the question became "active", so it was already bumped in some question lists.

You may try your luck posting a link to your answer off-site, and hoping that potential traffic will include users who can and want to upvote.