# I found a necroposter, what then?

Tags: discussion, answers, old-questions

I found a user resurrecting old (low-quality) threads. Their last six to eight answers were on old ('11--'14) resolved topics. Is there something I should do?

Comment: Why does something need to be done?

Comment: If they are good, valid answers that add to the discussion, vote them up!

Comment: Are the (new) answers repeating the existing answers, or are they different?

Comment: @Cerbrus My bad, it's last two answer are kind of good; the one he posted before I ask were low-quality answers, meant to farm votes maybe.

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, the problem is that the "necro-poster" is answering _low quality_ questions. To which I say - if the question is bad, downvote and/or close-vote the question, as appropriate.

Comment: Then the last 2 are fine. The other ones may need a downvote / low quality flag.

Comment: I'm looking forward to answer this question in 2019 - see you then :-)

Comment: Related: [I have a new answer for one (or more) old questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256207/3853934)

Comment: "Resurrecting" implies they were "dead". Why would you confuse "old" with "dead"?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On Stack Overflow, we're not too concerned about old questions becoming active again, provided whatever has changed is a good change.

Technology evolves and changes, and sometimes a new or updated answer can be posted to an old question. If the answer posted is of good quality, great! If it's new information posted to an old, highly viewed post, we don't want to discourage that.

If the new answers are duplicates, plagiarized, very low quality, or spam, they are not as welcome. *However,* this isn't just because they're on old questions. The same would be true if someone posted an answer with these qualities a day after a question was answered.

In short, handle new answers posted to old questions as you would new answers to new questions. Evaluate them based on content and act accordingly. Likewise, if you see these questions becoming active and *the questions* are low quality and need to be closed or deleted, handle *them* accordingly as well.

Answer (score 18):

Age of questions is of no importance. As long as the answers are good, there's no problem. If they're of low quality, you can vote, edit and/or flag them.

Answer (score 2):

We have [a review queue](//stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/stats) for handling this. Answering old questions is just fine, judging by the fact that one can complete a review in it with an upvote.

Comment: Of course, judging by the fact that there is a review queue for it, a large portion of them are problematic.

Comment: Note that the queue only handles late answers by users with < 50 reputation.

Comment: There's a [10k tool](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) for late answers. Also a [shameless plug](http://stackapps.com/questions/7049/natobot-bringing-10k-moderation-to-all). :)